# null | number is not assignable to number (even after making sure it cannot possibly be null)

Tags: typescript

I never used Typescript before and after some short tutorials I started converting an app. Mostly it goes smooth but in certain situations I feel like TS does not understand the code. This is the latest situation I just can't understand:

```
interface APIresponse { someProp: number | null }
interface parsedAPIresponse { someProp: number }

let apiResponse: APIresponse = { someProp: null }

function parseAPIresponse(response: APIresponse): parsedAPIresponse {
    response.someProp = 1
    return response
}
```

... and TS complains about incompatible return value, number|null not assignable to number, even after assigning value 1 to it.

What I'm trying to do is parse response from API. API returns number|null and I can't do anything about it but I'm avoiding nulls in my app so I try to parse API response and convert nulls.

Not sure how to write this and completely avoid nulls after API layer of the app.

Comment: in this case, I think you need to use another variable (of type `parsedAPIresponse` and use some kind of typeguard. `if (response.someProp is number) parseResponse.someProp = response.someProp` . Pr use a default value, etc... anything that can guarantee that the parsed prop is a number and not null, for instance this would also work : `parsedResponse.someProp = response.someProp || 0` to use a default 0 fallback valule for `null` / `undefined`

Comment: `response` is technically still a `APIresponse`, you only modify `someProp` to be equal to `1`.

Comment: The type checking is approximate in Typescript. See also this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (see in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAUCSUIGcAOA9iLigN7K6EC2E6Uh+AXMiAK7UBG0yAPq2wA2g5AF8AUKEixEKfHCikAJhmx4iJcpRp0GzAVx4TxgiGGRx8wAErripFqpwF7KALzIKVWvUYt2wmLi4jBsIAhgwMTI8ooQTnaaABTOGg5oWKmuAJQsscoJLpqe4shlyKbm+RBKtkXp1SqZiaTIHmSl5V3eun7IWZoAdD2++Hz8AAydZcZdOGBsUCAxCsp1aRDiokA) for instance):

```
function parseAPIresponse(response: APIresponse): parsedAPIresponse {
    let parsedResponse: parsedAPIresponse = {
        someProp: response.someProp || 0,
    };
    return parsedResponse;
}
```

In this example, we create a new object of the correct return type, and return this one, so TypeScript understand that it's the correct return type expected.

To make sure the `number` field is indeed not a null, I chose here to use a default value of `0`, though of course there might be some other ways (you could throw an exception if the value is not a number, or use another default like `NaN` etc...).

Comment: yes, thanks. In my real code I wasn't using interfaces but quickly declared type inline, which made me avoid re-using the same type again for parsedResponse. But this simplified solution does make it clear.